# How can I use inline images in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I'd like to insert an image in the contents of the email I'm sending. How can I do that with Gmail?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[From About.com](http://email.about.com/od/gmailtips/qt/et_inline_image.htm):

[image]

> **Insert an Image Inline in Gmail**
>
> To add an inline image to an email you
>   are composing in Gmail:
>
> - Make sure rich text editing is turned on in the Gmail message you are
>     composing and Insert images is
>     enabled.
>
>   - If you see a Rich formatting » link above your message's text editor,
>       click it.
>   - See below for turning on image insertion.
>   - Drag and drop the image from its folder to the desired position in the
>       message.
>
> To use an image you found on the web,
>   or to upload from your computer if
>   dragging and dropping does not work:
>
> - Position the text cursor where you want the image to appear.
> - Click the Insert Image button in the message's formatting toolbar.
> - To upload an image from your computer
> - Click Choose File and open the desired graphic.
> - You can click Choose File again to add another image while others are
>     already uploading in the background.
> - Make sure the desired image is highlighted.
>
> To use an image located on the web:
>
> - Make sure Web address (URL) is selected.
> - Enter the image's URL under Image URL.
> - Click Add Image.
>
> Images you have uploaded from your
>   computer remain available in the
>   Insert Image dialog while you compose
>   the message (but not for other
>   emails).
>
> **Enable Image Insertion in Gmail**
>
> To turn on Gmail's Insert Image
>   button:
>
> - Follow the Settings link in Gmail.
> - Go to the Labs tab.
> - Make sure Enable is selected for Inserting images.
> - Click Save Changes.

Comment: but the image so added does not come in proper formatting i.e. the text will have to appear either above or below the image you can not use the space just in side of image.For example see this
http://superuser.com/questions/395651/proper-formatting-of-text-when-inlining-an-image-in-email

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **Google Chrome**, you can simply drag and drop an image onto the email body to insert it.

This works in the current dev version(6.0.447.0) but I am not sure about earlier versions.