# How to workaround Gmail loss of pasted image upon Print and Send?

Tags: gmail

1 In a Reply window containing text and image, Select All and Copy.

2 In another Reply window, Paste

e.g.

[image]

3 Print.

Expected: Image included

Observed: Image lost - shows broken graphic icon and "image.png"

[image]

4 Send, and view sent message.

Expected: Image included

Observed: Image lost - shows broken graphic icon and "image.png"

[image]

Anyone know a workaround in Gmail, short of screen-capturing and pasting each affected image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that copy/paste doesn't upload the complete message content to Gmail and the print API can't access the temporary image that is used to render the messages in your web browser.

Options:

1. Download the image or get the image's URL then replace the image in the message with the downloaded image or the URL. For details about how to download images in Gmail messages see [Open & download attachments in Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/30719?hl=en).
2. Save the message as a Template, then insert it into other messages using the "More options" menu in the compose toolbar. **Note:** To use Templates they must first be enabled in [Settings > Advanced](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/advanced)
3. This last approach may or may not work depending on factors that include the way the image was added.  Copy the message to a word processor, Google Docs for example, then copy the content from that document to your message.

There are other options.

---

The problem occurs because attachments and images in emails are encoded in a special format for transport based on shared standards that allow unrelated SMTP servers to communicate. When you open a message with what appears to be inline images, Gmail has actually converted the underlying encoded image into a temporary source file that your web browser can display but the underlying image isn't available to Gmail print API.

References

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol

Related from this site

- [How can I use inline images in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/619/88163) from 2010
- [How to send email with images (embedded) in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/7635/88163) from 2010
- [Adding a Snagit image to the body of an e-mail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/13292/88163) from 2011
- [Why I cannot paste images from Snagit to Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/84262/88163) from 2015

Related from Super User

- [Directly paste clipboard image into gmail message](https://superuser.com/q/125237/152004) from 2010